# Calling APPSYNC mutation from Lambda with Cognito User Pool - UnauthorizedException

Tags: lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I am trying to Invoke a mutation from Lambda which is triggered by a timer on regular basis. This is what I am doing

```
const params = {
    AccountId: "XXXXXXX",
    RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/appsync_lamda_role",     // tried removing this too
    IdentityPoolId: "ap-southeast-1:xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx",
    LoginId: "demo_access" // tried with and without this
};
AWS.config.update({
    region: "ap-southeast-1",
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params)
});
```

Now, I call

```
 AWS.config.credentials.get(err => {

    const signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(httpRequest, "appsync", true);
    signer.addAuthorization(AWS.config.credentials, AWS.util.date.getDate());


 const options = {
        method: httpRequest.method,
        body: httpRequest.body,
        headers: httpRequest.headers
    };

    fetch(uri.href, options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(`JSON Response = ${JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)}`);
            callback(null, event);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(`FETCH ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)}`);
            callback(err);
        });
});
```

When I do this, I get an error from APPSYNC as  "errors": [
        {
            "errorType": "UnauthorizedException",
            "message": "Unable to parse JWT token."
        }
I have given access to role to invoke GraphQL and edited trust relationship

```
 {
     "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
       },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
    }
```

What I am missing here? Please help.

When I look at the headers generated, I do not see JWT token, but i see session token 
Like

```
 'User-Agent': 'aws-sdk-nodejs/2.275.1 linux/v8.10.0 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs8.10',
host: 'xxxxx.appsync-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'X-Amz-Date': '20181213T080156Z',
'x-amz-security-token': 'xxxxxx//////////xxxxxEOix8u062xxxxxynf4Q08FxxxLZxV+xx/xxx/xxx/xxxxx=',
Authorization: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxx/20181213/ap-southeast-1/appsync/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

AWS AppSync supports authorization via IAM and via Cognito User Pools. They can be confusing and in my experience the AWS documentation and frameworks do not help in this confusion.

IAM authentication is what all main AWS endpoints use. You can create a DynamoDB table with the right IAM authentication and permissions. IAM requests are made (often by the SDK or boto) by signing certain host, path, params and headers with your key converting it into a signature. Your Authorization header starts with AWS4-HMAC-SHA256, so it looks like you use IAM authorization with a v4 signature.

Cognito User Pool authentication is using JWT tokens for authorization. After authenticating with the Cognito server you get an access token and an identity token and they can be used to invoke resources like AWS Appsync. 
Using these access tokens you **can** retrieve IAM tokens if you connect your Cognito User Pool with a Cognito Identity Pool. If you do that you can use these tokens to sign requests for IAM authentication.

It looks like you configured your AWS AppSync API with Cognito User Pool authentication but you are invoking it using IAM authentication. You can either start invoking it using JWT authentication or switch your AWS AppSync API to use IAM authentication. Which authentication method you choose has influence on how you can enforce fine grain access controls (in an IAM policy vs in your GraphQL schema). Read more about it in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html).

Comment: Thanks @bram for your reply. Since my appsync API is used by mobile clients and has been running for some time, going back to IAM is not a feasible option now. What I was hoping for was acquiring a temporary token,  and pass this JWT token.  If I look at the credential param.WebIdentityToken, I can see something like a JWT token under, but this doesn't get used for signing.

Comment: Cognito User Pool authentication works by passing the JWT token in the Authorization header. A JWT token can not and should not be used to sign a request. Cognito User Pool authentication relies on other security mechanisms (https) to make sure the request has not been tampered with.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import URL from 'url';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from 'aws-sdk';

const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' });
const initiateAuth = async ({ clientId, username, password }) => cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.initiateAuth({
    AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    ClientId: clientId,
    AuthParameters: {
      USERNAME: username,
      PASSWORD: password,
    },
  })
  .promise();

export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const clientId = 'YOUR_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID';
  const endPoint = 'YOUR_GRAPHQL_END_POINT_URL';
  const username = 'COGNITO_USERNAME';
  const password = 'COGNITO_PASSWORD';
  const { AuthenticationResult } = await initiateAuth({
    clientId,
    username,
    password,
  });
  const accessToken = AuthenticationResult && AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
  const postBody = {
    query: `mutation AddUser($userId: ID!, $userDetails: UserInput!) {
        addUser(userId: $userId, userDetails: $userDetails) {
            userId
            name
        }`,
    variables: {
        userId: 'userId',
        userDetails: { name: 'name' },
    },
  };

  const uri = await URL.parse(endPoint);

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    headers: {
      host: uri.host,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: accessToken,
    },
  };
  const response = await fetch(uri.href, options);
  const { data } = await response.json();

  const result = data && data.addUser;
  callback(null, result);
};
```

Make sure that your Cognito User Pool has `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` authentication flow.

Comment: Where is the `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` flow set in Cognito User Pool?

Comment: check this:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/amazon-cognito-how-fix-error-auth-flow-enabled-client-malik/